# How can Add two different field which type is ObjectId in same object which refer same schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
const ChatSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
  },
  mobile: {
    type: Number,
  },
  friends: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "ChatSchema",
    },
  ],
  chating: [
    {
      senderId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "ChatSchema",
      },
      recieverId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "ChatSchema",
      },
      text: {
        type: String,
      },
    },
  ],
});


module.exports = mongoose.model("ChatSchema", ChatSchema);
```

when i update my schema with necessary data it give **error : maximum stack size exceed. **

```
const data = await ChatSchema.findById(req.params.id);
    req.userData.chating.push({
      senderId: req.userData, //if i replaced req.userData with req.userData._id it works.
      text: req.body.message,
      recieverId: data, //if i replaced data with data._id it works.
    });
    await req.userData.save();
    data.chating.push({
      senderId: req.userData,  //if i replaced req.userData with req.userData._id it works.
      text: req.body.message,
      recieverId: data, //if i replaced data with data._id it works.
    });

    await data.save();

    res.status(200).json({
      data: req.userData,
      error: false,
    });
```

Note: when i remove any on either recieverID or senderId from schema then it work fine with req.userId or data instead of req.userId._id or data._id respectively.

If any solution is possible then reply me.

Comment: `recieverId` should also be of type `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` (not `db.Schema.Types.ObjectId`)

Comment: I replaced db from mongoose but  doesn't work. Can we design schema like my schema